# Excel addin deployment problem

Tags: vsto, clickonce, excel-addins

I have created Excel addin.

Addin will never check for updates, User will update the addin.

Excel is launched from the c# application, after launching Excel uses addin to perform actions.

The problem is sometimes though Excel has updated version of the addin still it shows the "Updating Office customization" dialog box and will create the directory in AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 folder.

Why Excel is updating the customization though its having latest version of the addin.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using VSTO, from which .NET version?
check the publish section of the project properties... on the "Updates" button, you should see the 3 options for an excel addin to update itself.

if you select the check whenever the addin is being executed. the Excel will check for an updated version every time.

now you haven't say if excel will actuall update the add in version or not. but please check the above first

Comment: @meetjaydeep: did this help you? do you need any additional help? please accept my answer if you're ok